# nodejs soap can not create client properly from wsdl file

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, npm

I'm willing to connect to a soap service with nodejs. I looked for some modules to help me generate envelopes and soap related stuff for me. Turned out, `soap` module has a straight forward method for creating a soap service client. I could use this module for a couple of different services and they worked well, but I came across this one:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var client;

var url = "https://pgws.bpm.bankmellat.ir/pgwchannel/services/pgw?wsdl";
soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) {
    console.log('Client is ready');
    console.log(client.describe());
});
```

This snippet is not creating the expected soap client.
Can anyone please give a lead? I don't know what possibliy is the problem or how can I fix it.

Comment: Can you describe how what is being created is different from what is expected? Have you tried logging err?

Comment: @RayStantz sure, you can find a few operations in the wsdl file, but what this program creates is an empty service. I have tried logging err, that is null.

Comment: I noticed that you're using https -- do you have the proper root CA certificates installed?  Also maybe you should try adding the following within your function `if (err) throw err;`